# Headers in /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits not in /usr/include/bits

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to build NACHOS using a Makefile. I just installed gcc-3.3.6 and whenever I try to do "sudo make" the program fails because it says that its looking for the headers in /usr/include/bits and its not finding them. For some reason, the headers that its looking are in /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits. I am running ubuntu 12.04 and 32 bits.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please move this questions at http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: `sudo make` should **never** be run, use `make` followed by `sudo make install`

Comment: This is happening because of the multiarch spec.  3.3.6 is going to be too old to know about the multiarch spec.  Use a newer compiler!

Comment: but I need to use gcc 3.3.6 to compile the NACHOS libraries I'm using. Other compilers don't work.